# Client-Server C++ alternative for _kbhit() function

Tags: c++, input, client-server, nonblocking

My project is a Client-Server app (C++), more specifically a Group Chat.

I have built the Client and Server in 2 different solution in VS17.

Now, my problem is that when I want to send the message from one client to server-and the message to be redirected to the other clients connected- I do not want to be a blocking function, so I `used _kbhit()` function, but I doesn't work properly. Is there any alternative for input in the Client rather than `kbhit()` + `getch()` or `cin` ?

**Client**

```
char buffer[20];
int point = 0;

while (1)
{       
        if (!_kbhit()) {

            char cur = _getch();
            if (point > 19) 
                point = 19;
            std::cout << cur;
            if (cur != 13)
                buffer[point++] = cur;
            else {
                buffer[point] = '\0';
                point = 0;
            }

        }
        BytesReceived = recv(sock, buf, 4096, 0);
        if (BytesReceived != 0 && BytesReceived != -1)
        {
            cout << BytesReceived << endl;
            cout << string(buf, 0, BytesReceived) << endl;
            ZeroMemory(buf, 4096);
        }

    //cin >> userInput;
    // non blocking input 

    //if(userInput.size()>0)
        //int sendResult = send(sock, userInput.c_str(), userInput.size(), 0);
        int sendResult = send(sock, buffer, point+1, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

In ncurses you could try `nodelay()` function to turn getch() into a non-blocking call, which returns ERR if no key-press is available.

Answer (score 0):

I think that should be:

```
if (_kbhit () != 0) {
    ....
```

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58w7c94c.aspx